# Using values for a ListBox from a text file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am currently trying to make a ListBox its values from a text file - values.txt

The values.txt file contains a different value on each line e.g.

```
Value1
Value 2
Value3
Value 4
```

How could I use the values in this text file to be used within the ListBox?

Comment: [`System.IO.StreamReader.ReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx) is the method you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first read the text using either StreamReader or File.ReadAllLines.
Then, add the data to your ListBox.
Example:

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\file.txt"));
```

It should work.

Comment: James Make sure to accept answers to your comments :) other wise you may not get replies to youre future questions